Django 4.2.15 on Cloud Run - Severe Slowdown with uWSGI and High `domLoading` Time, But Only in One Project


I'm encountering severe performance issues with my Django 4.2.15 application when running on Google Cloud Run. However, the problem seems to be isolated to this specific project, as other projects on Cloud Run do not exhibit the same behavior. Here are the details:

Django version: 4.2.15
Environment: Google Cloud Run (1 Core, 2 GB Memory)
Web Server: uWSGI 2.0.26 (Nginx is not being used)
Database: MySQL (queries are not the bottleneck)
First response When checking in Chrome's Network tab, the initial document load takes 2.04 seconds.
Issue: The site is significantly slower on Cloud Run compared to my local environment.
Observation: The Django Debug Toolbar shows that about 90% of the total time is spent during the domLoading phase, which is disproportionately long.
Caching: The site performs well when serving cached views (i.e., when database access is avoided).
Local Environment: The application runs very quickly locally without any noticeable delays.
Cloud Run Details:

The slowdown occurs even when no other users are accessing the service.
This is not due to a cold start; the service is already running.
Other projects on Cloud Run do not experience this issue.



Additionally, I created a simple static HTML page with the following content:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello world</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello world!
</body>
</html>

This page is rendered using a basic Django TemplateView as shown below:
path('plane/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='plane.html'), name='test'),

Despite its simplicity, this page takes around 2 seconds to load on Cloud Run, which is far too long.
Given that this issue is specific to this project and does not affect my other Cloud Run projects, I suspect there may be something unique about this project's configuration or setup that is causing the problem.
Could this be related to the way uWSGI is configured, or might there be other factors within this specific project that are contributing to the slowdown? Any insights on how to diagnose or resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Additional Information: Safari and curl Results
Safari:

domLoading: 2963 ms

curl:

http_code: 200
time_total: 6.228104
time_namelookup: 0.003261
time_connect: 0.017354
time_appconnect: 0.078004
time_starttransfer: 6.095002

Change from uWSGI to Gunicorn
I switched from uWSGI to Gunicorn, but there was no improvement in loading speed.


Not sure if it's a red herring, but domLoading hints a browser side issue. Have you tried using curl or another browser to access the same page to see if it's as slow?

Thank you. I was using Chrome, so I added the results from Safari and curl to the question. The response was slow in all methods.

Interesting. My second suggestion would be to (temporarily) replace uwsgi with something else, such as gunicorn or even the development server to see if it makes a difference.

I switched to Gunicorn, but there was no change. I have added a screenshot to the question.

Must be a Cloud Run thing, unless it's a bug in your Python code. Possibly a load balancer thing? Not sure. Added the tag so that Cloud Run experts can see the question.

Oh, just noticed that you said "The site performs well when serving cached views (i.e., when database access is avoided).". If this is still accurate it must be a database thing.

Thank you. So, it seems the database is the cause.
When running locally, I am connecting to the same database as on Cloud Run, but the results are returned quickly. In the first image, the SQL section of the Django debug toolbar shows around 14ms. If you know of any method to investigate where the issue might lie in the database, please let me know.

After initializing a new Django project, it performed quickly. Additionally, when I added only the post app, which connects to the database, and tested it, the results were returned immediately. This indicates that there is an issue with the Python code. However, the project is complex and involves multiple apps, so to identify the root cause, it seems I have no choice but to strip down functionalities one by one until it becomes fast enough. If there is a more efficient method for investigation, I would like to know.

It is hard to say anything without seeing your code, but I would start by profiling the code using something like https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk (unless you are using async, because afaik silk is not async-compatible).

You're right, I'll give django-silk a try. Thanks for pointing me to a new middleware.

I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause, but it seems that the Service Worker was causing the problem. Removing the Service Worker fixed the problem of extremely slow loading.

If it was the service worker curl would've worked faster as it doesn't execute Javascript.

It's true that JS (Service Worker) shouldn't be a problem with curl. However, I haven't made any changes other than the Service Worker, and now both the browser and curl return results in 1-2 seconds.
